# Targeting images of div repeatedly

Tags: jquery, image

I am trying to target every first and every second image of div.

```
<div class="poscik">        
    <div class="post-image-film">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/film_hover.png" />        

       <img src="
                <?php
                if ($image_url_sm) {
                    echo $image_url_sm[0];
                } 
                else {
                    echo bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . "/images/generic_thumbnail.png";
                }?>
        " />    
</div>
```

First is hover effect of other.

```
$('.post-image-film img').eq(0).css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'z-index': '2'
}).hide();

$('.post-image-film img').eq(1).css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'margin-top': '-270px;'
});

$('.poscik').hover(function () {
    $("img", this).eq(0).fadeToggle();
});
```

This is what I got so far. Due to the fact that class `"poscik"` is repeated. This only applies to first div `class="poscik"`. In order to rack other images i need to switch to `eq(3)` and `eq(4)` and so on. This is impossible for me. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The CSS :nth-child should do the trick.

Comment: `$("img", this).lt(2)`

Answer (score 1):

You've two, relatively simple, options to select the first two elements:

```
$('.post-image-film img:lt(2)')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LpJEL/).

And:

```
$('.post-image-film img::nth-child(-n + 2)')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LpJEL/1/).

References:

- [CSS `:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).
- [`:lt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).

Comment: Great. Final outcome: $('.post-image-film img:nth-child(1)').css({'position' : 'absolute', 'z-index' : '2'}).hide();
$('.post-image-film img:nth-child(2)').css({'position' : 'absolute', 'margin-top' : '-270px;'});

$('.poscik').hover(function() {
 $("img:nth-child(1)", this).fadeToggle();

});

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it will work:

```
$('.post-image-film img').children(':eq(0)').css({'position' : 'absolute', 'z-index' : '2'}).hide();
$('.post-image-film img').children(':eq(1)').css({'position' : 'absolute', 'margin-top' : '-270px;'});

$('.poscik').hover(function() {
    $("img", this).children(':eq(0)').fadeToggle();

});
```

Comment: Nope. Children has no attribute 'eq'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd suggest you should take a look at the [editing-help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/), to see how to format your answer appropriately. =)